# Vue Router doesn't work on Azure App Service

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, azure-appservice

I'm developing webpage with vue.js.
vue-router works well on debug. Howerver, all page except the root (/) return 404 not found whent it is deployed to Azure App Service.

- My Environment

  - Windows
  - Node.js 16.14.2
  - Vue.js 3.2 + TypeScript
  - @vue/cli 5.0.4
  - vue-router 4.0.14

My source code like the following:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Home from '@/components/home/Home.vue';
import Price from '@/components/price/Price.vue';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/price',
    name: 'Price',
    component: Price
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
});

export default router
```

```
<script setup lang="ts">
</script>

<template>
  <div>
      <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router/index';
import 'windi.css'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

the root page is fine, so I think vue-router is working.
So I tried change Vue of the root page from 'Home' to 'Price'. Then, the 'Price' page was return in the root (/).
Why aren't other pages working?

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Price,
  },
  {
    path: '/price',
    name: 'Price',
    component: Home
  },
];
```

Comment: vue-router is likely not the issue. 404 is a HTTP status code from your web server. Make sure to configure your web server to have routing that either redirects to root or broader routing to render your SPA.

Comment: I add web.config to public directory and the issue has been resolved. I'll write answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've added web.config to directory '/public/' to resolving IIS routing issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="SPA" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```